# I was asked to leave a store for no reason,then employee snatched item out my hand that belonged to me, I was the ordered out of the store,legal?

Tags: criminal-law, discrimination, civil-rights

I went to the store to return a item but I didn't have the correct receipt,so continued into the store to purchase other items.The Mgr came up to me and told me to leave the store, I asked him why?He told me he didn't need a reason.as I'm exiting the store store I explained to him that the item in my hand was my property (the item I came to return).He said it was not .I told him to check the camera, or ask the lady at customer service,which he refuses, then another employee physically snatched my property out of my hand.the Mgr. then said that he would physically remove me out of the store,if I didn't leave, I then exited the store.what are my legal options if any ?

Answer (score 1):

You do have the option to let it go, but presumably you want the item returned. You claim it is your property, they claim it is theirs, you have a simple ownership dispute that could be resolved in small claims court. What you do there is basically explain the circumstances and bring the receipt as evidence that it is you property. You may have a cause of action regarding the forceful grabbing of the item and the threat of force (the legal alternative would be for them to detail you until the police arrive), so hire a lawyer to deal with this situation.